# code to build systems of equations

Tags: system

I asked the question before but I forgot my login information:

here is the question:
[How many equation systems can I build from five equations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137983/how-many-equation-systems-can-i-build-from-five-equations)

the code works good but miss some equations
for example if we have A1,A2,A3,A4  the code will give us

```
 {A1 == A2 && A2 == A3},
 {A1 == A2 && A2 == A4},
 {A1 == A3 && A3 == A4},
 {A2 == A3 && A3 == A4}
```

there are some systems lost like:

```
{A1 == A2 && A3 == A4},
{A1 == A3 && A2 == A4},
{A1 == A4 && A2 == A3}
```

Can anyone help me and fix the code so we can find all systems.

Thank you

Comment: Is this what you want? `And @@ Equal @@@ ## & /@ Nest[Subsets[#, {2}] &, {A1, A2, A3, A4}, 2]`

Comment: @halirutan Thanks for your answer. How can I find the solution for every system. I will defined Ai as equation of a and b.